# updating data in angular without refreshing or loading the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm implementing a wishlist and I would like to delete content from the wishlist without needing to refresh the page in order to see the new data. 
Here is what I did:

```
wish.controller('wishCtrl',['$scope','$http','$cookies','$window',function($scope,$http,$cookies,$window) {


    var user={};
    user.email = $cookies.get('cookieEmail');
     $http.get("http://localhost:3000/wishlist/"+user.email).success(function(data){
        $scope.wishController = data; 
        console.log(data);
    });



        var delclick=0;
        var newView =0;

        $scope.delClick = function(title, des, subj) {

        var wish = {};

        wish.user = $cookies.get('cookieEmail');
        wish.sub = subj;
        wish.title = title;
        wish.description=des;

        console.log(wish.user);
        console.log(wish.title);
        console.log(wish.sub);
        console.log(wish.description);

        delclick=1;

        if(delclick==1)
            {
               $http.post('http://localhost:3000/wishlistDel', wish).then()
               //$scope.load();
               //$window.location.reload();
            }

          }

}]);
```

As you can see in the comments I tried `$window.location.reload();` but it's like refreshing because the whole page is uploaded again instead of removing one item -  like `display:none`, is there any way to do that?

***edit***

```
        <div ng-repeat="wishlist in wishController.Themes" >
                 <h2 class="text-center">{{wishlist.title}}</h2>
                 <h2 class="text-center">{{wishlist.description}}</h2>
                 <img ng-src="{{wishlist.image}}" class="imgCenter">
                 <button class="w3-btn w3-ripple" ng-click="delClick(wishlist.title, wishlist.description, wishlist.sub, $index)">click </button>
         </div>
```

**update**

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/wishlistDel', wish).then(function () {
   if(item.sub=='party'){
    var index = $scope.wishController.Party.indexOf(item);
    console.log(index);
    if(index !== -1){
     $scope.wishController.Party.splice(index,1);
    }
}
    if(item.sub=='activity'){
    var index = $scope.wishController.Activity.indexOf(item);
    console.log(index);
    if(index !== -1){
     $scope.wishController.Activity.splice(index,1);
    }
}
    if(item.sub=='theme'){
    var index = $scope.wishController.Themes.indexOf(item);
    console.log(index);
    if(index !== -1){
     $scope.wishController.Themes.splice(index,1);
    }
}

});
```

}

Comment: Can sure simplify this by passing in your original object from the view

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `delclick=1;` and then immediately testing `if(delclick==1)`?

Comment: You add $index on ng-click, but not in your function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the easiest way to manage all of this is pass the original object into your `delClick` function from the view.

Relying on using `$index` from view is not safe if any filters are used in `ng-repeat`

This allows you to simply index that object within array you want to remove it from. It also means you don't need to rebuild  new object to send to server

```
<div ng-repeat="wish in wishlist">
   {{wish.something}}
  <button ng-click="delClick(wish)">Delete</button>
```

In controller

```
$scope.delClick = function(item){
   $http.delete("http://localhost:3000/wishlist/"+user.email +'/' + item.id).then(function(){
     var index = $scope.wishlist.indexOf(item);
     if(index !== -1){
       $scope.wishlist.splice(index,1);
     }
  });    
});
```

Comment: * $scope.wishlist.splice(index,1);

Comment: @charlietfl I can't use my post function? it has to be delete?

Comment: Yes you can ... using `delete` is *"Restful"* approach. Server then just checks what method is used on that same url

Comment: @charlietfl I updated it - this is what you meant? it's still not working for me...

Comment: @charlietfl the automatic deleting without needing to refresh

Comment: edited html doesn't show you passing object in from view. Do some console logging to see what is what and check errors thrown

Comment: sorry didn't really understand. so this function is not for deleting it from the html? because deleting an object from the wishlist DB is working fine...
is there a way to do so without needing to refresh or reload the page?

Comment: oh yes it is for deleting from html. When you add or remove from array...angular automatically updates the view

Comment: ok great! so I understood fine :)
so know my from is that is not happening it just deleting without changing the view so I probably didn't understand it fully. 
 $scope.wishlist.splice goes to the array in the controller?

Comment: I called it `$scope.wishlist` before you showed actually array name....need to use actual array `Themes`

Comment: I have three different arrays in the page that call the same function
1. wishlist in wishController.Themes
2.wishlist in wishController.Activity
3.wishlist in wishController.Party

so how do i call all of them?

Comment: would need another argument then that tells you if it is `"theme"` or `"party"` or `"activity"` so you know which array and what url to use

Comment: I updated it again.. i'ts still not working :( without $http.post('http://localhost:3000/wishlistDel', wish)
I see the correct place of the index in my console.log but with this function - it doesn't go inside

Comment: add error handler to `$http`. if not going inside request might not be working properly. Can also cut down all that code duplcation by simply defining which array to splice

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the collection of data you have is on `$scope.wishController`. You need to update this collection specifically and remove the deleted item:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/wishlistDel', wish);
$scope.wishController.splice(indexOfDeletedItem, 1);
```

Since you are passing in `$index` you would want to use:

```
$scope.wishController.Themes.splice($index, 1);
```

Comment: I was just writing the same answer ! Too slow

Comment: suggest splicing in success of request though

Comment: @charlietfl not necessarily; I would prefer that the deletion is reflected immediately rather than having to wait for the server. If there is a server / deletion error it could restore the item, though.

Comment: right, would need to store copy then for rollback in view though

Comment: @ExplosionPills so my function needs to return the index of the deleted item and that will be sent in splice?

Comment: @user3488862 you need to pass that index into the delete function. I think we probably need to see your template to do that

Comment: @ExplosionPills template of my html? or my db?

Comment: @user3488862 need to see how you are calling `delClick`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass on template the `$index` of wish on `ng-click` and remove it on controller, something like this:

On template:

```
<a ng-click="delClick(title, des, subj, $index)">Delete {{wish.title}}</a>
```

On controller, you will need to change your function to receive this, and remove item from your list model:

```
// Here you'll need to receive the $index from template
$scope.delClick = function(title, des, subj, index) {

    // ...

    if(delclick==1) {
        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/wishlistDel', wish).then(function () {
             // Here you'll use the same array of your 
             // ng-repeat instead $scope.list
             $scope.list.splice(index, 1);
        });
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to use filters, I recommend something like [this](https://github.com/rafaelcneves/desafio-frota/blob/master/js/frotas/controllers/frota.js#L53) or the @charlietfl answer

Comment: strongly suggest not using `$index` and do own indexing. If any filters used in `ng-repeat` then  `$index` will be index of filtered array not master and will end up removing wrong item

Comment: where to put $index?

Comment: `$index` is an variable from ng-repeat, and angular sets this, you don't need any action to set, you'll use it on ng-click and get on controller to do what you want https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: If you would like to use a filter like @charlietfl said, you'll need to use something like this https://github.com/rafaelcneves/desafio-frota/blob/master/js/frotas/controllers/frota.js#L53